# regular graphs with the smallest eigenvalue -2?

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

I'm searching for regular graphs with the least eigenvalue -2. Is there any characterization or something that represent all these graphs?also number of vertices is power of n?

Answer (score 10):

Connected regular graphs with smallest eigenvalue at least $−2$ are either a line graph, a cocktail party graph, or the number of vertices is at most 28.

P. J. Cameron, J. M. Goethals, J. J. Seidel and E. E. Shult, [Line graphs, root systems, and elliptic geometry,](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869376901629) J. Algebra 43, 305–327 (1976).

This is Theorem 3.12.2 in [Distance-Regular Graphs](https://books.google.nl/books?id=v6brCAAAQBAJ) (2012).